# How to get the value for multiple subnode in xml?

Tags: c#, asp.net

1. Xml code:

   ```
       <Report>
         <ChartData>
           <ListName>area</ListName>
           <ViewName>Selecte List</ViewName>
           <YAxisFields>
             <YAxisField>
               <Name>Scheduled Start Date/Time</Name>
               <DataType>DateTime</DataType>
               <Category>Year</Category>
             </YAxisField>
           </YAxisFields>
           <XAxisFields>
             <XAxisField>
               <Name>Release Type</Name>
               <DataType>String</DataType>
               <Category>
               </Category>
             </XAxisField>
           </XAxisFields>
         </ChartConfig>
      </Report>
   ```
2. I got the value for the subnode listname and viewname by using the
                   below code,

   ```
       XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
       doc.Load("XmlFileName"); 
       XmlNodeList node = doc.SelectNodes("Report/ChartData"); 
       foreach (XmlNode xn in node) 
       { xn["ListName"].InnerXml = chartname; 
       xn["ViewName"].InnerXml = SelectedList; 
       **xn["YAxisFields/YAxisField"].InnerXml = yaxisfield; //not working, need to get the value for this xml node,need help in this line dono how to proceed**
       doc.Save("XmlFilename"); 
       }
   ```
3. First i have tried with code like this instead of above code,in this
                   i need to create number of objects in order get the value for each
                   node so i tried by creating object for xmlnodelist then i used
                   foreach loop to get the value for each node but in this couldnt get
                   the value for YAxisFields/YAxisField because it also has parent node
                   as YAxisFields and subnode as YAxisField so there is only way to
                   create number of objects for xmlnode or is there any other way to do
                   this?

   ```
       XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
       doc.Load("XmlFileName");
       XmlNode Listnode = doc.SelectSingleNode("Report/ChartData/ListName"); 
       XmlNode Viewnode = doc.SelectSingleNode("Report/ChartData/ViewName");
               if (Listnode != null)
               {
                   Listnode.InnerXml = chartname;
                   Viewnode.InnerXml = SelectedList; ;
                   doc.Save("XmlFileName");
   ```

Comment: Are you able to use LINQ to XML instead? It's generally simpler than the old API... (It's also not really clear what you're trying to do...)

Comment: you XML is not valid by the way this tag does not match starting tag on line #2 `</ChartConfig>`

Answer (score 1):

Use Linq to XML XDocument, like this:

```
doc.Root.Descendants("ChartData").ToList().ForEach(node =>
                {
                    node.Element("ListName").Value = chartname;
                    node.Element("ViewName").Value = SelectedList;
                });
```